# CRM Plugin: how to update email address of account soon after its creation

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise version.

I have an "account" entity and I want to update that account email with hardcoded value soon after its creation.

I want to do this in a plug-in which runs on the "account" entity when you create that account. When you do so, email address of that account gets created.

I've done a bit of searching for this, but there's nothing out there which shows the email ADDRESS getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you really want to do your things after creation of account:
You need to register your plugin on **Post Operation** and after that target entity has to be updated via Organization Service.
Like:
Post Operation:

```
target["emailaddress1"] = "new@test.com";
organizationService.Update(target);
```

OR Just use **Pre Operation** change the email address and that's it.

Here is a sample:

```
public class TestPurpose : IPlugin
    {
        private Entity target;

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext pluginExecutionContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory organizationServiceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            IOrganizationService organizationService = organizationServiceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(pluginExecutionContext.UserId);
            target = pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
            //This is what you need
            target["emailaddress1"] = "test@test.test";
            organizationService.Update(target);
        }
    }
```